# how to redirect from one portlet to another inside plugin project in liferay 7

Tags: jsp, liferay-6, liferay-7

I have created liferay plugin project - Liferay MVC, and Created Multiple liferay portlets under this plugin project.

Now I need to navigate from one portlet jsp to another portlet jsp file.

how to do this using liferay 7.

For your referrence : 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWj3O.png

**My view page :** I have tried like below :

```
<liferay-portlet:renderURL portletName="offer" varImpl="redirectURL">
<liferay-portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/offer/index.jsp" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stops you from doing exactly the same?

By default, you have your .jsp files in `src/main/resourses/META-INF/resources` folder. Put your jsp's there and create the same `renderURL`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... I am not having "src/main/resourses/META-INF/resources" by default. Im using Ant, so default i have **docroot/html/portletname/view.jsp**

Comment: I found the solution . 
<portlet:renderURL var="offerURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/offer/index.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<a href="<%=offerURL%>">Offer</a>

using the above code we can navigate from one portlet to another.